# How to add a right margin to AvalonEdit number line?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, margins, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit WPF control with a .Net Framework 4.8 project, using Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 10 64bit.

I need to add a right margin to the linenumbers. To understand what i need i attach a selfexplanatory image:

[image]

My actual xaml code is next:

```xml
<avalonEdit:TextEditor
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
    xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
    xmlns:editing="clr-namespace:ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Editing;assembly=ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit"
    xmlns:rendering="clr-namespace:ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Rendering;assembly=ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit"
    Name="TextEditor"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    SyntaxHighlighting="C#"
    ShowLineNumbers="True"
    FontSize="10pt" Margin="0">
</avalonEdit:TextEditor>
```

Hope that someone can give me a hand on this, i spend two days trying to add this margin but couldn't achieve a proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The margin you see now comes from DottedLineMargin, see https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/774b38e672b3f4252f9f4e6f2f3f6707ea7fb943/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Editing/DottedLineMargin.cs#L29. Your best bet is probably going to be to implement a custom margin class that is similar (but doesn't show the line) and adding it to TextArea.LeftMargins (or you could replace DottedLineMargin with your own version, and just adjust the margin there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the approach in my comment will work, I thought of an even easier way. Just copy the style for TextArea from the source and modify it to include some margin on the right of the ItemsControl that contains all the editor's margins. The style is here:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/395ef8166870e2c6e1f63a7d97ac22e5e646e790/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/TextEditor.xaml#L42

And here's a complete example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1_SO_AvalonEdit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
    xmlns:editing="clr-namespace:ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Editing;assembly=ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit"
    Title="Main Window"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Shared="False" TargetType="{x:Type editing:TextArea}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.7" Color="#3399FF" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBorder">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Pen>
                    <Pen.Brush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#3399FF" />
                    </Pen.Brush>
                </Pen>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type editing:TextArea}">
                    <DockPanel Focusable="False">
                        <ItemsControl Margin="0,0,10,0" Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LeftMargins}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <ContentPresenter Panel.ZIndex="-1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TextView}" Focusable="False" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <avalonEdit:TextEditor Name="TextEditor" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="10pt" ShowLineNumbers="True" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also wait until the editor is loaded and then find the ItemsControl in the visual tree and adjust the margin, from code.

Answer (score 2):

Can get this by setting the innter TextView's margin:

```cs
TextEditor.TextArea.TextView.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);
```